# MySQL - Order by number of chars

Tags: php, sql, mysql, select

I have the most simple SQL

```
SELECT * FROM words
```

It has 13000 words (varchar). I need to get the longest word first in my output. I guess it might be possible with the WHERE command?

**Alternative**

If it doesn't work like that, is there a smart way to sort my output array so it will order it by the longest word first (in the 'word'-column). It looks like this (in the output loop)?

```
$output_array[$row['word']] = $row['another_word'];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ordering the words by its length should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM words
ORDER BY LENGTH(word) DESC
```

Comment: Will that work even though VARCHAR is padded to a given length?

Comment: @Adrian Schmidt: What do you mean by padded?

Comment: @Adrian Schmidt: CHAR is padded, VARCHAR isn't.

Comment: @Adrian Schmidt: varchars are not padded, chars are.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from words order by len(my_field) desc;
```